# Como agregar un cero a la derecha para acompletar mi flotante a 3 decimales en C#

Tags: c#, float

tengo un programa que sube cantidades en decimales y requiero que sean a 3 decimales para que sea más exacto y a veces me salen 0.22 como puedo hacer para agregar un cero en caso de que salgan dos o un decimal?

```
double galones = Diferencia / Balance; 
galones = Math.Round(galones, 3);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! "tengo un programa que sube cantidades" a donde? porque los decimales 0 a la derecha desaparecen siempre salvo que pases cadenas... estas pasando cadenas???

Comment: No tienes que redondear si tu objetivo es solo mostrar. Usa algo como `Console.WriteLine(galones.ToString("F3"));` para mostrar solo 3 decimales por consola. Tienes una [lista inmensa](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-6.0) de formatos para tu número con solo pasarle un argumento a `ToString`.

Comment: ¿Y si es una variable así como...? galones[5].ToString("F3"); me sale un error: